# How can add a new voice assistant (other Country) on Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Can anyone help?

I'm in doubt how to add the voice assistant Francisca (Brazil) in Bixby Studio.

If this is possible, can you help me?

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator in Bixby Developer Studio should already use this voice if you have a pt-BR target defined as Francisca is the only voice for that locale.

Comment: Yes, I’m glad to say that, more in the simulator / Studio by bixby you don’t have the option of mobile Portuguese BR, you only have in English and Korean to select.  do you think you can download a language en to install in Bixby Studio?